# How to represent a complex MongoDB query as URL params

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a MERN app that will allow me to query my database for users with skills. My issue is I am hitting an API endpoint to search for these users in my mongoDB database, and I'm not sure how to represent these queries in a URL params string.

If i want to find users who have React skills greaters than 3 years experience, and have SQL skills with greater less than 5 years, and have C++ skills with 1 year experience,  here is the query for mongoDB:

```
 User.find({
  $and: [
    { skills: { $elemMatch: { skill: 'React', yearsExperience: { $gt: 3 } } } },
    {
      skills: { $elemMatch: { skill: 'SQL', yearsExperience: { $lt: 5 } } },
    },
    {
      skills: { $elemMatch: { skill: 'C++', yearsExperience: 1 } },
    }
  ],
})
```

Here is how that data for the user is stored in the database:

```
skills: [
{skill: 'React', yearsExperience: 3},
{skill: 'HTML', yearsExperience: 5},
{skill: 'JavaScript', yearsExperience: 5},
{skill: 'SQL', yearsExperience: 3},
{skill: 'TypeScript', yearsExperience: 1},
{skill: 'C++', yearsExperience: 1}
]
```

I am trying to convert the first query into a url to pass to my API to get the relevant users but I am unsure how to represent all that info in params. I have tried with no luck:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/v1/user?skills=React,[gt]3&skills=SQL,[lt]5&skills=C++,1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

For such a complex filtering maybe it would be considerable to use POST with json body as a filter, for example:

```
POST http://localhost:1337/api/v1/user/search
```

```
{
  "conditions": [
    {
      "class": "skills",
      "field": "React",
      "type": "GT",
      "value": "3"
    },
    {
      "class": "skills",
      "field": "SQL",
      "type": "LT",
      "value": "3"
    },
    {
      "class": "skills",
      "field": "C++",
      "type": "EQ",
      "value": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Provided structure is, of course, not ideal, and you can modify for your cases better.